# Ionic libraries Jquery conflict

Tags: jquery, angular, ionic-framework, froala

I have an ionic application and I am using 2 libraries **Angular FullCalendar** and **Froala Editor**.

**The Froala Editor requires to import this**

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

window["$"] = $;

window["jQuery"] = $;
```

**And the FullCalendar requires to do this.**

`declare var $: any;`

and use it like this : `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('next');`

Both are different pages and still getting errors when I open the calendar.

This is the error:

> TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function at
>   CalendarPage.webpackJsonp.261.CalendarPage.GetCalendarEvents

How can I avoid this conflict?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Out of curiosity. Do you need to use that Angular FullCalendar or you can use another calendar? It's not good practice to use jQuery in angular applications

Comment: Did you run? npm install jquery?

Comment: @PatricioVargas Yes I need to use them now. No I didn't install jquery. It comes with the ionic.

Comment: hmmm..i don't think it does

Comment: There's no mention of JQuery on the npm page for fullcalendar (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-fullcalendar)? Are you sure you can use that syntax?

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialization. 
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/installation
This method was used.